# About web scraping in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

There are two major variables (calls and puts), and several sub-variables (e.g. bid, change, time etc.) For example, if there are total 5 data points. I know how to do separately:

```
data[u'options'][0]["calls"][0]["change"]['fmt'], data[u'options'][0]["calls"][1]["change"]['fmt'], data[u'options'][0]["calls"][2]["change"]['fmt'], data[u'options'][0]["calls"][3]["change"]['fmt'],data[u'options'][0]["calls"][4]["change"]['fmt']
```

but that spend too much time. I wonder how to choose multiple items in one code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a little bit of list comprehension if I understand your question properly.

For each value in `data["options"][0]["calls"]`, it adds that value's ["change"]["fmt"] value to the list.

```
d = [call["change"]["fmt"] for call in data["options"][0]["calls"]]
```

If you want a list of EACH value from every set of options, you could do it like so:

```
d = [[call["change"]["fmt"] for call in option["calls"]] for option in data["options"]]
```

and now you can say

```
for option in d:
    for call in option:
        print(call)
```

Comment: one more question, how could I name the last step? For example:
'A = for option in d:
          for call in option:
             print(call)', I know this is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
[data[u'options'][0]["calls"][i]["change"]['fmt'] for i in range(5)]
```

I don't quite understand your problem, is this what you're after?

Comment: Yes, this what I mean. Thanks